# How can i call this function in another view controller?

Tags: swift, function, syntax, model

I have a model in which i set this function up to check to see if the current user has a Role. I keep throwing errors when i try to call this code in a different view controller function...Im not quite sure on the syntax, its my first time trying to call a function like this. Thanks.

```
class AdminCheck {

  func getAdmin(completionHandler : ((Admin : Bool) -> Void)) {

var roleQuery = PFRole.query()
roleQuery!.whereKey("name", equalTo: "admin")
roleQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() { (roleObject: PFObject?, error) -> Void in

  var adminRole = roleObject as! PFRole

  adminRole.users.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error) -> Void in


    if let objects = users {

      if objects == PFUser.currentUser() {

        completionHandler(Admin: true)

      } else {

        completionHandler(Admin: false)
```

my call is looking like this..

if  AdminCheck.getAdmin {(Admin) -> void in

couple errors I'm getting...
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Bool'

Comment: getAdmin don't return a boolean value. You can't use: `if AdminCheck.getAdmin { (admin) -> Void in
} `

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.  It's a good idea to play around with this in an XCode sample project.

```
class AdminCheck {    
    func amIAdmin(handler: (Bool) -> Void) {
        handler(false);
    }
}

var ad = AdminCheck()

ad.amIAdmin { (result:Bool) -> Void in
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something will like this.

```
class AdminCheck {

     class func getAdmin(completionHandler : ((admin : Bool) -> Void)){
          // your handle
     }
}
```

And use it.

```
AdminCheck.getAdmin { (admin) -> Void in
     // your handle
}
```

Comment: do i put this inside a function? the class as well? for example..  func isAdminOrNot() {
    
    class AdminCheck {
      
      class func getAdmin(completionHandler : ((admin : Bool) -> Void)){
        // your handle
        AdminCheck.getAdmin { (admin) -> Void in
   
        }
        
        
       
        if  (admin == true)  {
     
          
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toAdmin", sender: self)
  
    }else {
    
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toEmployee", sender: self)
       never have called this before...

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I see your question. You call a class function. And i suggest you. How to use it.